Uniqueness of solution of the Dirichlet problem of second order elliptic equation in small region.
I'm reading the book "Ladyzhenskaya Utraltseva Linear and Quasilinear Equations". On p.9, the last paragraph, it says

We know that,for such equations, the theorem on the uniqueness of the
solution of this problem in the class of classical solutions is valid
"in the small;" that is, the Dirichlet problem has only one classical
solution if the domain of definition of these solutions is
sufficiently small.

and "such equations" in this paragraph, they mean second order linear PDE of elliptic type.  I think they don't mean the maximum principle since the maximum principle requires that $c \le 0$ and holds on any domain.
Then, what does it mean by saying "uniqueness is valid in the small"? Can any one give me some references on this result?

I think I got it. Uniqueness follows from Fredholm's alternatives.
